# Solrnet simple grouping

Tags: grouping, solrnet

Has anyone been able to group in Solrnet but use group.simple parameter?

This is url returns what I want:

```
solr/DWBusHeading/select?q=Pizza&fq=BUS_SERVICE_AREA:Regina&bq=BUS_CITY:Regina^5&qt=/DWSearch&group.field=BUS_DW_CUST_ID&group.field=BUS_BUSINESS_NAME_EXACT&group.field=BUS_CITY_EXACT&group.format=simple&group.main=false
```

which returns the results I want.

```
Dim groupcol As String() = {"BUS_DW_CUST_ID", "BUS_BUSINESS_NAME_EXACT", "BUS_CITY_EXACT"}

options.Grouping = New GroupingParameters() With { _
    .Fields = groupcol,
    .Format = GroupingFormat.Simple,
    .Main = False}
```

but I get a {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} error when performing the query in Solnet.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/solrnet with full stack trace please.

Comment: The consultant I used for Lucid realized she gave the incorrect information.  With grouping.simple, you can only group using one field.  We were trying with 3 fields.

Comment: I'd still like some more info, to avoid a NullReferenceException.